# Modify textbox width to display all data in xhtml primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces, xhtml

I have read-only textboxes in a form that auto-populate data from a table.

```
<p:inputText value="#{ManagedBean.var}" styleClass="textbox" id="varDetails" maxlength="200"></p:inputText>
```

Some entries are not displayed completely because they exceed the textbox width.
How can i use the Onmouseover command to change the width of the textbox dynamically?

Comment: Check properties 'onmouseover' and 'onmousouse'. You can also do it with [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<h:form> 
    <p:inputText ... 
                 onmouseover="$(this).attr('size', this.value.length)"   
                 onmouseout="$(this).attr('size', '')" />
</h:form>
```

You'd have to use `min-width` and not `width` in the styleclass.

But if the content is smaller than the current size, it will also become smaller. If you don't want that you can use something like

```
onmouseover="if (this.value.length > 10) $(this).attr('size', this.value.length)"
```

The value (10 above) should be chosen so it matches the min-width in the styleclass.

Otherwise you could give it a title:

```
<p:inputText ... value="#{ManagedBean.var}" title="#{ManagedBean.var}" />
```

That will be shown onmouseover.

You could also give it a `p:tooltip`:

```
<p:tooltip for="varDetails" value="#{ManagedBean.var}" />
```

That's more or less the same.

Comment: Is it working ok for you @Manish Chawla ? I think another option is to use a javascript library (which don't care where the input's come from, Primefaces or not)

Comment: Made a slight few changes since it disturbed the layout of my table on runtime. Other than that, it works fine for me @jaquen H'ghar. A man is grateful.